# How to enable/disable text box based on radio buttons using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 radio buttons and 2 text boxes. I want to enable/disable text boxes based on radio buttons. When page first loads, `txtB` should be disabled. And it will be enabled only when its respective radio button `B` is checked. Can you please guide me how to do this?

JQuery

```
 $("document").ready(function () {
           $('#M').on('change', '.ABC input[type = "radio"]', function () {
                    var divA = $('.P').find('#A'); 

                    var lblA = $('.panel-heading').find('#lblA'); 

                    var id = $(this).val();              
                    if (id == "A")
                    {

                        $(lblB).hide();
                        $(lblA).show();
                    }


                   $('#' + id).show();

               });
        });

       $("document").ready(function () {
           $('#M').on('change', '.CDE input[type = "radio"]', function () {                           
                    var lblA = $('.panel-heading').find('#lblA'); 
                    var lblB = $('.panel-heading').find('#lblB'); 

                    var id = $(this).val();              
                    if (id == "B")
                    {
                        $(divA).hide();

                        $(lblB).show();
                    }

               });
        });
```

Radio buttons

```
<div class="ABC">
                <label>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Name, "A", new { 
                       @checked = "checked" })<span>A</span>
                </label>
           </div>
       <div class="CDE">
           @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Name, "B")<span>B</span>
       </div>
```

Textbox

```
    <div class="P">
        <div id="A" class="container">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtA)
         </div>

    </div>     

    <div id="B">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtB)                         
     </div>
```

Comment: what is language with markup

Comment: @Dipakchavda, this is html5 with MVC framework

Comment: Disable or hide? (your code is attempting to show/hide it, not disable/enable it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Disable/Enable

Comment: Use `var selectedValue = $('input[name=name_of_your_radiobutton]:checked').val();` to get the value of the selected button then all you need is an `if` block and use `$('#txtA').prop('disabled', true);` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke, shall i use the code you mentioned in the above JQuery?

Comment: You just need one function (like in the answer by Shiladitya). But that answer depends on giving your textboxes an `id` attribute that matches the corresponding radio button value, which may not be what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `txtB` disabled using `disabled` attribute.

```
<div class="ABC">
     <label>
         @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Name, "A", new
         {
             @checked = "checked"
         })<span>A</span>
     </label>
</div>
<div class="CDE">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Name, "B")<span>B</span>
</div>

<div class="P">
    <div id="A" class="container">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtA)
     </div>
</div>
<div id="B">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtB, new
        {
               // Make this textbox disabled as you need this textbox to be disabled on page load
               @disabled = "disabled" 
        })
</div>
```

Use the following jquery,

```
// Fire on radio button checked event    
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {

    // Get the value of currently clicked radio button
    var value = $(this).val();

    // Find the corresponding textbox inside the div that has the id same as radio button value and remove it disabled attribute
    $('#' + $(this).val())
    .children('input[type="text"]')
    .removeAttr('disabled');

    // Find all radio button and find its corresponding textbox and make it disable except the checked radio button.
    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
        if(this.value != value)
        {
            $('#' + this.value)
            .children('input[type="text"]')
            .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Solution works perfectly fine in the given scenario. Thank you so much.

Comment: If it is working for you please accept it as your answer @Raj

Comment: But Can you please guide me if there are 3 radio buttons and 4 texboxes.

Comment: You can use the same code but you have to follow the naming convesions that you have done. That means you have to make sure that the value of radio button must be same as the id of div where you have the textbox corresponding to that radio button.

Comment: If there are 1 more radio button inside the same `<div>` and it looks like `<div class="ABC">
     <label>
         @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Name, "A", new
         {
             @checked = "checked"
         })<span>A</span>
     </label> <label>
         @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Name, "C")<span>C</span>
     </label>
</div>`

Comment: and then 2 more textboxes on click of radio button `C` which looks like `<div class="P">
        <div id="A" class="container">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtA)
         </div>
<div id="C" class="container">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtC)
                               
                              
                                <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtD)
                                 
                                </div>        
           </div>
    </div>`

Comment: please help me. If I implement the same code then on click of radio button `B`, only `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtC)` gets disable but logically `txtC` and `txtD` gets disabled.

Comment: what about textbox txtD , is this txtD has no radio button? Then when you have to disable/enable this txtD?

Comment: I got the solution now. Thank you so much for showing me the path.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
  $('#' + $(this).val())
    .removeAttr('disabled')
    .siblings('input[type="text"]')
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="text1" checked name="textbox">Textbox 1
<input type="radio" value="text2" name="textbox">Textbox 2

<br/>

<input type="text" id="text1" />
<input type="text" id="text2" disabled/>
```

Hope this will help you.

**Details:**
Which ever radio button will be clicked corresponding textbox will be enabled.

**Assumption:**
Your textbox are siblings

In your scenario,

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
  $('#' + $(this).find('span').text())
    .find('input[type="text"]')
    .removeAttr('disabled')
    .closest('div')
    .siblings('div')
    .find('input[type="text"]')
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
});
```

Comment: Please help me with my scenario. Please do not create separate one. It would be good if you answer my question with my scenario. Thanks

Comment: @Raj I've updated the answer, have a look and please let me know.